# The power supply is damaged instantly

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I ordered a PCB from JLCPCB with a DC/DC converter on it. It is a 12V to 3.3 V DC-DC converter. However, when I received it and connected, it instantly damaged. Now it shows zero ohms resistance between 12V terminal and GND terminals of the DC/DC converter. I thought it must be a problem with the soldering or part, I tested another PCB and I also damaged it. I want to understand what the reason is.

DC/DC converter: K7803M-1000R3

Datasheet: [Like to datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811051114_MORNSUN-Guangzhou-S&-T-K7803M-1000R3_C132363.pdf)

Circuit diagram:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Board placement:

[image: Board placement]

Update:
Entire project is available here:

https://oshwlab.com/gadisureshkumar/iot-can-master

Comment: Use an ohmeter on a blank board and make sure traces don't connect to traces they are not supposed to connect to.

Comment: Did you solder it in backwards, perhaps? Are you giving it an input voltage within its ratings? We can't tell you what's wrong without plenty more information.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I powered it with 12V and it is damaged. :(

Comment: @Hearth, It is not done by me. It is soldered by the JLCPCB guys. And I saw it is good and correct. I mean the polarity is correct and there was no continuity between 12v and GND at the beginning.

Comment: Ehhh...remove a new DC-DC converter from teh board and connect it without the board. See if it explodes.

Comment: What's that trace almost shorting the two terminals of the capacitor on the bottom of the image? Did your board pass the DRC?

Comment: Which EXACT model of the DC:DC is fitted: K78LXX-500R2 has two variants. one aligns with the PCB, the other will short it out

Comment: @DamienD, Yes, it passed DRC

Comment: @JonRB, it is K78xxM-1000R3

Comment: @JonRB, How would I know which one is which? Does it mean, I lost these boards for ever?

Comment: @DKNguyen, I applied just the 3.3v and see that circuit is working as expected.

Comment: As DKNguyen says *remove a new DC-DC converter from teh board and connect it without the board*.  Apply 12V and ground and see if you get 3.3V.

Comment: Which trace is +12V, thicker or thinner?

Comment: Perhaps the fault is not in the DC-DC converter. Maybe it is a PCB manufacturing error, or PCB design error, which might be even in the schematics. There is no way to tell that unless full schematics and PCB design is available.

Comment: @Justme, I am sharing the entire project. It is available at: https://oshwlab.com/gadisureshkumar/iot-can-master

Comment: in my opinion the traces run on top of each other. Did you run a drc before ordering?

Comment: @SKGadi what you uploaded doesn't seem to include the trace layout, but what we can see from the picture you've added above this is badly layouted, and broken (no solder mask opening over some pads, overlapping traces,…) and if my memory of JLCPCB's tolerances serves me well, should **not** have passed DRC. Your layout is broken. Redo it!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, There are several PCB layouts. May be you are seeing the wrong one. The one I used is this one. https://easyeda.com/editor#id=9aa133e4ddba47a9854f329101ed23db

It is passing the DRC.

Comment: @SKGadi that dead stub at your lower electrolytic's - contact is <0.15 mm close to your positive trace. If this passes DRC, DRC was not configured well.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I saw it now. I don't know why DRC test results are good for me. Thank you for being meticulous. Let me pull the module out and see if it works independently.

Comment: @SKGadi I don't know what's going on with EasyEDA there. There are two areas on your board where the rounded end of a thick track comes within 0.127mm of another track. The DRC doesn't catch it when set to 0.15mm, but does when set to 0.16mm. This may be a bug in how EasyEDA handles distances to linecaps, you could report it to them. In the meantime advise setting more conservative DRC values, especially as your board isn't too dense.

Comment: Also note that all these errors are caused by traces that you don't actually need, because they are redundant with the GND flood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. I made two sillies but dangerously damaging ones.

1. As @DamienD mentioned, the GND PCB trace is close to 12V trace
2. I connected the power supply in reverse polarity. It happened because I made a mistake in the silkscreen with bad polarity signs.

So, I must say this is because of extremely poor PCB design on my part.